# Showing exception when i am adding label on uitableviewcell using auto_layouts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

Hi i am tyrying to adding UILabel on tableview cell using auto
_layouts programatically constraints with item but label is not adding on cell

adding like below image

[image]

What did i do wrong here.

## My Code is below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {

        formulaLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        formulaLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Bold" size:16.0f];
        formulaLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        formulaLabel.text = @"Ramakrishna";
        formulaLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:formulaLabel];

        NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:formulaLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:40.f];
        [cell.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:formulaLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
        [cell.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:formulaLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f];
        [cell.contentView addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:formulaLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [cell.contentView addConstraint:constraint];       

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is formulaText ? You should not do constraint setup in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. Consider creating UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: What exception ? Where is it?